# Which 18-pin automotive connector is this?

Tags: part-identification, connector

What type of automotive connector is on the images below? The last image (from device docs) says "pa66-gf35" which leads me to this [Tyco Electronics connector catalogue](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&ved=0ahUKEwjgi7j_l_DMAhUiEJoKHaGqCKQQFghTMAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.te.com%2Fcommerce%2FDocumentDelivery%2FDDEController%3FAction%3Dshowdoc%26DocId%3DCatalog%2BSection%257F1307992-2_GET_64_Interconnection_System%257F1209%257Fpdf%257FEnglish%257FENG_CS_1307992-2_GET_64_Interconnection_System_1209.pdf%257F1393366-1&usg=AFQjCNGtiT7Y4X70C_7jYGIMazPqSlh3CA&sig2=UmtNOHru4aXpfADzduDVtA&bvm=bv.122448493,d.bGs&cad=rja) where this "housing material" is listed about 60 times - I have no idea if one of the connectors is the one I need though. The connector has 2x9 pins. The dimensions below are in mm.

Here is the connector on device - I need the female part for the cable:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the device?

Comment: I simply got it as spare part but without cabling. It is an ACC radar by the way.

Comment: What car did the ACC module come off of?Are there any part numbers on the module itself?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that this is one of Delphi's own proprietary connectors - it's not a Tyco one.

From a cursory search, the mating connector appears to be "Delphi 13658062". However there is no datasheet for that one for some reason.

There is information on the [Delphi 13658063](http://delphi.com/manufacturers/cv/connection-systems/catalog/feature?search=13658063) which is the same except for the locating notch position. In fact if you look at the images (they supply images not a pdf just to be awkward), you will see that the 13658062 is listed there and has the correct alignment notches.

---

Doing some further looking, it seems to also be equivalent (perhaps a new number) to the [Delphi 13699658](http://delphi.com/manufacturers/cv/connection-systems/catalog/feature?search=13658063#) which does have the alignment notches.

---

As a side note, I also found the [pin-out](https://fccid.io/pdf.php?id=1084989) in case you need it.

Answer (score 1):

My guess when it comes to your contact is that it is a standard 2x9 (2.54 mm/ 0.1 in) pin connector housed inside some company's exotic socket. My suggestion to you would be to get a IDC Socket 2x9 pin 0.1 in Female with ribbon cable. 
This seems to be supported by page 6-46 in the PDF that you linked. It seems that their 2x9 connector could also fit you system.

If you want the exact connector type and name I'd suggest to start with looking at the device where the connector is located and looks at the vendor's website. If they have tech support you could mail them and ask.

Comment: Thanks for valuable answer. The IDC is a good idea but I am afraid I will need thicker wires than the standard PC IDE cables :). What is the thickest AWG that IDC can handle? Can you suggest there to go for such IDC connectors in Europe?

Comment: Seems that Tom Carpenter is on it! When it comes to thickest AWG and vendors, I'm no better at using the search engines than you are! :) Mouser/Elfa/Farnell might be worth to check.

Answer (score 0):

The connector are 1488533-5 or 2203663-5 they are similar.
About notch - for this radar sensor need the black one.
[LINK ABOUT NOTCH's](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Customer%20Drawing%7F2203663%7FA7%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CD_2203663_A7.pdf%7F2203663-5)